# How does OpportunityAccessLevel field behave on Account Team Member object?

Tags: sharing, account-teams

I have a situation where the User(say User-A) which is the owner for Account and associated Opportunity record but still unable to select 'Read/Write' access in OpportunityAccessLevel field when adding user(say User-B) (who is above in role hierarchy & have profile 'System Administrator').

System only show following fields: Private or Read Only

Whereas when a user(say User-C) with 'System Administrator' profile & role same as 'User-B' try to give access to User-B, then the option of 'Read/Write' started to appear.

Org-Wide-Default setting for Account and Opportunity is set to 'Private'

Additional Info: When User-A (owner of the Opportunity) try to give access to User-B via Opportunity Team, the access level 'Read/Write' appears on field Opportunity Access